# Conversion - beginner

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**I have a hard time doing the arithmetic statement**

Convert the tuple, "Third" to an array.

Double all the elements in "Third"

Add the elements in this array to the elements in "Fourth".

To do this, use only 1 arithmetic statement. Store this result as "Fifth" and print it.

Hint Answer should look like this:

Fifth = 2****(***_) + _____
print (Fifth)

```
third = (-6,-18,-10,-4,-90,-55,-56)
fourth =[6],[18],[10],[4],[90],[55],[56]
fourth = np.array(fourth)
print(third)
print(type(third))
print("After converting Python tuple to array")

arr = np.asarray(third)
print(arr)
print(type(arr))

fifth = 2*arr
print(fifth)

output:
(-6, -18, -10, -4, -90, -55, -56)
<class 'tuple'>
After converting Python tuple to array
[ -6 -18 -10  -4 -90 -55 -56]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

[ -12  -36  -20   -8 -180 -110 -112]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `numpy.ndarray` type ([docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html)) supports addition using the `+` operator. However, in your example my guess is that `2*arr + fourth` will not produce the result you are looking for because `fourth` is of shape `(7,1)` while `arr` is of shape `(7,)`, so `arr + fourth` would be of shape `(7,7)`.

There are multiple ways to get `fourth` into shape `(7,)`. `fourth.flatten()` will work ([docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html?highlight=flatten#numpy.ndarray.flatten)), as will [numpy indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html), e.g. `fourth[:,0]`.

Try this runnable (and editable!) example

```js
import numpy as np

third = (-6,-18,-10,-4,-90,-55,-56)
fourth =[6],[18],[10],[4],[90],[55],[56]
fourth = np.array(fourth)
print(third)
print(type(third))
print("After converting Python tuple to array")

arr = np.asarray(third)
print(arr)
print(type(arr))

print(f"{arr.shape=}, {fourth.shape=}, {fourth.flatten().shape=}, {fourth[:,0].shape=}")

fifth = 2*arr + fourth[:,0]
print(f"{fifth=}")

fifth
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js"></script>
```

p.s. when asking a question make sure to post your attempt as well as the traceback of the error produced

Comment: When I run the code it doesn`t do the fifth = 2*arr + fourth[:,0]
print(fifth)

Comment: @mmm18 does it work for you now? before I was just calling `print(fifth)` at the end not actually returning a value

Comment: This is fantastic, considered impossible to implement with reasonable effort for the stackoverflow developers. Before using it, I prefer to wait for the official reaction of Stack Overflow

Comment: @Modularizer it still doesn't work, python is not running the statement

Comment: @mmm18 sorry to hear that! I hope that the python solution works for you in your own IDE. If you are having trouble with the runnable code feature in the sample above I would love to work with you to debug if you wish to create an issue [here](https://github.com/modularizer/pyprez/issues/new) or explain more in depth what is going on

Comment: @Modularizer - Correct output for me with Chrome on Ubuntu 22.04.